# load test debugging is not working

Tags: .net, tfs, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I have a load test (using VS2012). The problem is that debug is not working (it just runs without hitting any breakpoints), and stack traces for exceptions are not available (it shows only "-" in the appropriate column).
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

UPD I have to remind that in .NET release configuration *does* contain debug information, though somewhat less detailed. Building in release config *doesn't* remove stack traces nor disables breakpoints.

Comment: Are you building in release mode? With release mode, you get no debug information (including stack traces with line numbers).

Comment: Did you check all the project configurations to make sure that even though it says "Debug" that one of the projects isn't building in release mode?

Comment: This question seems local to your install. I'm using VS2012 and it debugs fine. This might seem generic but try a re-install

Comment: @Carl Saldanha, already did.

Comment: can you try debug the solution on another machine?

Comment: Also are the break points in the tests or the code being tested? if it is the code being tested then you may want to try disabling code coverage

Comment: Breakpoints are in in the tests. Debugging of other solutions works well, only the load test solution can't be debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception was inside VS load tester code itself (but reported as thrown from my code), that's why it was without stack trace, and debugging of my own code never started.